# on the decline or in decline

Tags: phrase-usage

What is the difference between *on the decline* and *in decline*
As I observe, the preposition *on* follows by definite article while the other does not.

Are both use replaceable?

Comment: You should add some actual usage sentences where you found these terms. It might help you evaluate potential differences.

Answer (score 1):

Both phrases are commonly used, as well as, "on a decline". AFAIK, they have identical denotation and connotation, and can be used interchangeably... As well as "He's going downhill."

Oddly, "*It's* going downhill," can mean, "It's *not* doing as well as before," or, paradoxically, the antithesis, "It's *getting easier*," as in walking downhill after a long trek to the summit.